# Converte string para numérico em javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando converter uma string para um numérico, a questão é que tenho máscara na string e o número é um valor grande fazendo com que o valor total não seja somado corretamente.

Preciso que após somar o valor, voltar a mascara com . e , dessa forma 10.000.034,89

```
var Total = 34.9; // esse valor vem dos outros campos acima...
var i = 4; // loop for.
var Dezembro = "9.999.999,99"; //  vem de um getElementById
if (Dezembro != "") {
  Dezembro = Dezembro.replace(".", "");
  Dezembro = Dezembro.replace(",", ".");
  if (!!Dezembro.match(/^-?\d*\.?\d+$/)) { Total = Total + parseFloat(Dezembro); }
}

var Total_ = (parseFloat(Math.round(Total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)).toString();
Total_ = Total_.replace(".", ",");


document.getElementById("BodyContent_livCamposForm_NuTotal_" + i + "_txtNum_" + i).value = Total_;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muda

```
Dezembro = Dezembro.replace(".", "");
```

para

```
Dezembro = Dezembro.replace(/\./g, "");
// ou
Dezembro = Dezembro.split(".").join("");
```

Como tinhas o replace só substitui a primeira que encontra.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hfrLwy5p/

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda....