# Como fazer contas com números muito grandes?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma fórmula enorme, e preciso trabalhar com números tipo 4,2803917^-12, só que quando tento fazer conta com eles, recebo como resposta NaN. Como posso trabalhar com eles em javascript?

Comment: já tentou converter pra número? note que vírgula não é um valor válido, e o "^" deve ser substituído por "E", assim por exemplo: `Number("4.2803917E-12")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"preciso trabalhar com números tipo 4,2803917^-12"* note que, como está esse valor ele não e válido para converter para número diretamente em `Javascript`.

É preciso usar o formato com "ponto" para decimais e "E" para o exponte, assim por exemplo:

```js
console.log(Number("4.2803917E-12"));
console.log(Number("4.2803917E-12") * 2);
console.log(Number("4.2803917E-12") / 2);
console.log(Number("4.2803917E-12") + 10);
```

Se precisar converter a string para esse formato tem várias perguntas aqui no site, por exemplo essa: [Converte string para numérico em javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108566/57220)